# log4j:ERROR Failed to flush writer, java.io.IOException: The handle is invalid

Tags: spring, log4j, tomcat7

I am using log4j1.2.17 with my spring web app (Spring 3.2.1). I am getting the following issue intermittently. Sometimes it comes on startup itself and sometimes on request handling. Following is the stack trace.

```
log4j:ERROR Failed to flush writer,
java.io.IOException: The handle is invalid
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.writeBytes(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.write(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.writeBytes(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.implFlushBuffer(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.implFlush(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.flush(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.OutputStreamWriter.flush(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.log4j.helpers.QuietWriter.flush(QuietWriter.java:59)
    at org.apache.log4j.WriterAppender.subAppend(WriterAppender.java:324)
    at org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender.subAppend(RollingFileAppender.java:276)
    at org.apache.log4j.WriterAppender.append(WriterAppender.java:162)
    at org.apache.log4j.AppenderSkeleton.doAppend(AppenderSkeleton.java:251)
    at org.apache.log4j.helpers.AppenderAttachableImpl.appendLoopOnAppenders(AppenderAttachableImpl.java:66)
    at org.apache.log4j.Category.callAppenders(Category.java:206)
    at org.apache.log4j.Category.forcedLog(Category.java:391)
    at org.apache.log4j.Category.log(Category.java:856)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.Log4JLogger.info(Log4JLogger.java:199)
```

When I debugged it appears that the file handle is closed already. Once when i was testing just before the exception, i got the following message from log4j

```
log4j:Finalizing appender named [stdout].
log4j:Finalizing appender named [logfile].
```

Not sure why it is getting finalized when application is still using it.

Below is my log4j xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE log4j:configuration SYSTEM "log4j.dtd">
<log4j:configuration xmlns:log4j="http://jakarta.apache.org/log4j/">

<appender name="stdout" class="org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender">
    <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
        <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d %p [%c] -  %m%n" />
    </layout>
</appender>

<appender name="logfile" class="org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender">
    <param name="File"
        value="E:/logs/bizscore.log" />
    <param name="MaxFileSize" value="5000KB" />
    <param name="MaxBackupIndex" value="3" />
    <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
        <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d %p [%c] -  %m%n" />
    </layout>
</appender>


<logger name="org.apache.commons">
    <level value="INFO" />
</logger>



<logger name="org.hibernate">
    <level value="INFO" />
</logger>

<logger name="org.springframework">
    <level value="INFO" />
</logger>

<root>
    <priority value="info" />
    <appender-ref ref="stdout" />
    <appender-ref ref="logfile" />
</root>

</log4j:configuration>
```

Any pointer will be of great help.
Thanks.